# How to use nested mongoDB query to calculate percentage?

Tags: mongodb

It is our coursework today, [this is the dataset](http://jse.amstat.org/datasets/titanic.dat.txt), and this is the column description:

```
VARIABLE DESCRIPTIONS:
Column
   1     Class (0 = crew, 1 = first, 2 = second, 3 = third)
  10     Age   (1 = adult, 0 = child)
  19     Sex   (1 = male, 0 = female)
  28     Survived (1 = yes, 0 = no)
```

and the last question is

> What percentage of passenger survived? (use a nested mongodb query)

I know if I am going to calculate the percentage, I use `.count` to find how many rows that Survive = 1, and how many rows in total and use `.find(Survive:1).count()` divide `.find().count()` , for now I know I can use aggregate to solve the problem but it does not meet the requirement. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show your data model (sample document from your collection) ?

Comment: @mickl Thank you for your reply. I would like to know do you mean the result of `db.titanic2.find()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering following data:

```
db.titanic.insert({ Survived: 1 })
db.titanic.insert({ Survived: 1 })
db.titanic.insert({ Survived: 1 })
db.titanic.insert({ Survived: 0 })
```

you can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html). `1` passed as a argument will give you total count while `$Survived` will count survived people. Then you can use [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html) to get the percentage.

```
db.titanic.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            Survived: { $sum: "$Survived" },
            Total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            SurvivedPercentage: { $divide: [ "$Survived", "$Total" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

which outputs: `{ "SurvivedPercentage" : 0.75 }`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet you're right, it will be fine in this case thank you